# Pass multiple objects to view through controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc web app in which I want to send 2 objects to View through Controller now I am sending only one object to view through controller

```
return View(repository.func(id));
```

and in view I am getting

```
<% var data = Model.First %>
```

But now I am confused how to send 2 objects and how to get it.

Comment: Are both of the objects of the same type?

Comment: Is the ViewBag/ViewData an option or does it need to be done through the Model?

Answer (score 4):

An excellent occasion to (learn to) use a ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel { ... }


// and in the Action:
var view = new MyViewModel();
view.First = repository.func(id) ;
view.Second  = ....;    
return View(view);
```

Comment: class MyViewModel {...} In the class What I need to be define. Please explain in details and how to get each object in view

Comment: Yes, you have to write a MyViewModel class. It will become the Model property inside the View.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewBag (Personally I don't like this approach) or create class which will hold both values and use it for model for your view

Answer (score 0):

I assume your view is strongly-typed to be of the same type as whatever you're returning from:

```
repository.func(id)
```

lets say object '`Foo`'

Assuming you are using a strongly-typed view:

```
@model Foo
```

You can change this to be:

```
@model IEnumerable<Foo>
```

Then, your view will be strongly-typed to a collection (IEnumerable) of Foo

and in your view you can do:

```
foreach(var foo in Model)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Naturally, your repository method will have to return a collection of objects (via something that implements IEnumerable - List<> for example)

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight elaboration of Henk's answer

```
class MyViewModel {
    TMyEntityType1 First { get; set; }
    IQueryable<TMyEntityType2> Second { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the action you collect your 2 sets of data and house it in an instance of MyViewModel

```
var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
viewModel.First = repository.func(id);
viewModel.Second  = repository.containing("?");    
return View(viewModel);
```

An in your view you may want to change it to:

```
<% var dataFirst = Model.First; 
   var dataSecond = Model.Second;%>
```

Where Model is now of type MyViewModel and not the return type of repository.func(id)