# ASP.Net MVC - Questions regarding databases, models & views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC4, C# and SQL CE 4.0.

- I have three tables in my database, I can't use separate models for them because when I try to do that, I'll encounter an error when running my app and browsing to the page. From what I observed, the addname in the connection string must be the same as the DbContext in the model, and with this, I'm forced to stick to one model.

My question is: Am I doing it right, is this practical and is there a workaround for this (multiple models, all connecting to the same DB but different table)?

- I'd like to display data from different tables in my database (something like collating them in one model?). How do I do that?

E.g. Table 1 has a "Title" column and Table 2 has a "Book" column. I'd like to display the data in the two different columns of the two different tables in one view. So, the view will display the Title and Book.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Multiples Entities passed to a single view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840969/pass-multiple-objects-to-view-through-controller)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of MVC is model view controller the model is a broad view of your database in another word if you look at the folders you will see that it created three folders for you there for it legitimate to have three two or more object class instances of your database in your model. you typically send one model object to the view such. in order to dispay several model in a view you can use partial view or you can use viewbag. or you can create another model just for the project to hold the data from two tables

here is tutorial

[ASP.Net MVC - Questions regarding databases, models & views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901968/asp-net-mvc-questions-regarding-databases-models-views)